# WSO2 IS IdP keystores

Tags: saml, wso2-identity-server

deploying WSO2 Identity Server as SAML IdP - there can be several keypairs (private key / certificate) in play:

- SSL keypair / certificate for administration console or/and services 
      this seems to be configured in carbon.xml
- keypair / certificate to sign the SAML responses - apparently the same keypair is used. Is it possible / where to configure the SAML IdP certificate?

Best regards
         Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the resident IdP uses the key configured in the carbon.xml / Security / Keystore

To update the default keystores check the resources:

- http://sencs.blogspot.be/2015/03/how-to-change-default-keystores-and.html
- https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB220/Changing+Default+Keystores